# Is it possible to ask for the Facebook login credentials only once and then save them and login without entering them again?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I would like to create a PHP/MySQL application where the owner of the application can add multiple Facebook accounts and use them to post on one or more pages.

After reading the Facebook Login API docs I understand that the only way to login a user is to generate the login URL and then enter the username and password in the generated page. This is ok, if you do it once, but it will be a pain in the ass to do it every time you want to post something form multiple accounts (by multiple I mean more than 50).

So here's my question: is it possible to ask for the credentials only once, store them some in the database and then just login by pressing a button? No popups, no nothing?

P.S. I know for sure its possible because I've seen this behavior in a desktop app.

Thank you!

Comment: No, that is not possible – and not allowed, your app must not ask users for their FB login credentials ever. If you are posting to pages _as_ the page, then get an extended page access token – those never expire by default. (And if you are talking about posting to user profiles, then you are doing something wrong to begin with – automated posting to those is not allowed, the user must actively trigger every single post.)

Comment: I'm sure that there's a way. Take a peek at http://postcron.com. They let you schedule posts and add multiple accounts.

Comment: Yea they store the page access token like @CBroe said